# Apache Error Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a linux vps that my php application runs on and I have been noticing that its performance has slowed down significantly recently. I checked the error logs and noticed that I have been getting these errors:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
> probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
> the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,
> referer: https://website.com/app/?id=12345

Here is my htaccess at the root of public_html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ CCA\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ CCA\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?website.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?website.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F]
```

Here is my htaccess in the application itself

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am unsure of what I need to do to remove this error.

Comment: "my htaccess in the application itself" - I assume you mean in the `/app` subdirectory?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite yes it is in the application subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

You're not checking that the target file (with `.php`) exists before rewriting. So any request (that does not already map to a file) where the corresponding `.php` file also does not exist will result in a rewrite loop.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

You don't need to backslash escape literal dots inside a regex character class. The `NC` flag is not required here.

---

*Aside:* The mod_rewrite directives in `/app/.htaccess` will cause the parent mod_rewrite directives to be completely overridden - so the HTTP to HTTPS redirect will not occur.